# Database driver (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver) is not present. Please install it on your application server

Tags: liferay

After installing Liferay and configuring it to use my database, I get this error:

> Database driver (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver) is not present. Please install it on your application server.

How to solve it?

---

[image]

Comment: I had to select MariaDB when I used the MySql from Xampp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Download the Java driver for your database. It is a .jar file such as `mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar` for instance. It can be found on your database vendor's website.
2. Put that JAR file in the Tomcat of your Liferay server, in the `lib/ext` directory. Example: `liferay-workspace/bundles/tomcat-8.0.32/lib/ext/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar`
3. Restart Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

Liferya DXP 7.2 version has missing this mysql connector jar so you need to place that jar file inside lib/ext.
I need to install mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar